# I keep getting NoneType when I try to convert user_id's to member usernames on discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

Having issues returning member id's when using this line of code, When I don't call anything and I just let it run as:

```
 table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {(entry[0])} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]})'
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))
```

I get the user id's stored on my database.

But as soon as I try to convert them to discord member usernames, I just get none-type objects

```
 table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.guild.get_member(entry[0])} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]})'
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))
```

More code was needed to answer this, so here it is

```
class HelpMenu(ListPageSource):
    def __init__(self, ctx, data):
        self.ctx = ctx
        super().__init__(data, per_page = 10)

    async def write_page(self, menu, fields=[]):
         offset = (menu.current_page * self.per_page) + 1
         len_data = len(self.entries)

         embed = Embed(title="Server XP Leaderboard",
                       colour=self.ctx.author.colour)
         embed.set_thumbnail(url = self.ctx.guild.icon_url)
         embed.set_footer(text = f"{offset:,} - {min(len_data, offset+self.per_page-1):,} of {len_data:,} members.")

         for name, value in fields:
             embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)
         return embed

    async def format_page(self, menu, entries):
        fields = []

        table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.guild.get_member(entry[0])} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]})'
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))

        fields.append(("Ranks", table))

        return await self.write_page(menu, fields)


class Exp(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @command(aliases = ['lvl', 'level'])
    async def rank(self, ctx):

        db = sqlite3.connect('xpdata.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # user_id = self.author.id
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
        #
        # cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM xpdata WHERE user_id = {user_id}  AND guild_id = {guild_id}')
        # for row in cursor.fetchall():
        #     level_display = row[3]

        cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id, xp, level FROM xpdata WHERE guild_id = {guild_id} ORDER BY xp DESC')
        xp_ranking = cursor.fetchall()

        #menu
        ranking_menu = MenuPages(source=HelpMenu(ctx, xp_ranking))
        await ranking_menu.start(ctx)

        #await ctx.channel.send('{} is currently level {} and rank {}'.format(ctx.author.mention, level_display))

bot.add_cog(Exp(bot))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have all the intents on?

Comment: I'm confused to what you mean

Comment: Do you have the discord privilege intents on? It's required for the bot to recognize the members in a server. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: I just enabled that, and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Also, I think you should use `ctx.guild.fetch_member('id here')` instead of `ctx.guild.get_member(entry[0])`. For your code, is `self.ctx` defined? Even though, this command is in a class, I think you should have arguments like `async def command_name(self, ctx)`

Comment: The entry[0] is the user ID, and yet self.ctx is defined I'll update the question

Comment: After changing what you reccomended, my output now looks like this: 
```
1. <coroutine object Guild.fetch_member at 0x000001828DE501C0> (XP: 800 | Level: 5)
 ```

Comment: Since fetch_member is an async function, you would want to use the await keyword in front of this function; to be more specific you want `await ctx.guild.fetch_member('id here')`.  If it outputs `unknow user` error and you are sure that the user with the id you provided is in the server, then you should check if you have `commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())` and the two intents button enabled in discord dev portal. Or if the error is `Value "id" is not snowflake`, then you should check if you had the right id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232492/discussion-between-tkperson-and-hunter).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I needed to turn on discord privilege intents.

You can do this at the discord dev portal.

Then I needed to initialize it with

`intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)`